# TabHost.TabSpec content not appearing

Tags: java, android, xml, tabs, android-tabhost

I have a TabHost in one of my activity layouts with 4 TabSpecs. I have set the content for each TabSpec to be a different LinearLayout, but only the first TabSpec actually displays the LinearLayout. I have tried many things but still can't figure out what's wrong. Here's my code:

```
 public class ConversionActivity extends Activity {
PhConversion phc = new PhConversion();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_conversions);
    TabHost th = (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.tabhost);
    th.setup();
    TabSpec spec1 = th.newTabSpec("TAB 1");
    spec1.setContent(R.id.tab1);
    spec1.setIndicator("pH");
    TabSpec spec2 = th.newTabSpec("TAB 2");
    spec2.setIndicator("Temp");
    spec2.setContent(R.id.tab2);
    TabSpec spec3 = th.newTabSpec("TAB 3");
    spec3.setContent(R.id.tab3);
    spec3.setIndicator("Length");
    TabSpec spec4 = th.newTabSpec("TAB 4");
    spec4.setContent(R.id.tab4);
    spec4.setIndicator("Volume");
    th.addTab(spec1);
    th.addTab(spec2);
    th.addTab(spec3);
    th.addTab(spec4);
```

and the XML code:

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:gesture-image="http://schemas.polites.com/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".ConversionActivity" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="8"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<TabHost
    android:id="@+id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </TabWidget>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/given"
                    android:textSize="32sp" >
                </TextView>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/ph"
                        android:textSize="20sp" >
                    </TextView>

                    <CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/phBox"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:onClick="disableOthersPH" >
                    </CheckBox>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/poh"
                        android:textSize="20sp" >
                    </TextView>

                    <CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/pohBox"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:onClick="disableOthersPOH" >
                    </CheckBox>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/h"
                        android:textSize="20sp" >
                    </TextView>

                    <CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/hBox"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:onClick="disableOthersH" >
                    </CheckBox>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/oh"
                        android:textSize="20sp" >
                    </TextView>

                    <CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/ohBox"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:onClick="disableOthersOH" >
                    </CheckBox>
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/phconvinput"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="5"
                        android:inputType="numberDecimal" >
                    </EditText>

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="2"
                        android:onClick="solveph"
                        android:text="@string/phsolvebutton" >
                    </Button>
                </LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/phsolution"
                    android:textSize="32sp" >
                </TextView>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal" >

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="@string/ph"
                            android:textSize="20sp" >
                        </TextView>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/phanswer"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="@string/somespace"
                            android:textSize="20sp" >
                        </TextView>
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal" >

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="@string/poh"
                            android:textSize="20sp" >
                        </TextView>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/pohanswer"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="@string/somespace"
                            android:textSize="20sp" >
                        </TextView>
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal" >

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="@string/h"
                            android:textSize="20sp" >
                        </TextView>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/hanswer"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="@string/somespace"
                            android:textSize="20sp" >
                        </TextView>
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal" >

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="@string/oh"
                            android:textSize="20sp" >
                        </TextView>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/ohanswer"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="@string/somespace"
                            android:textSize="20sp" >
                        </TextView>
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/phsolution"
                        android:textSize="32sp" >
                    </TextView>

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/what"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/phschem" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/hello_world"
                        android:textSize="32sp" >
                    </TextView>
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab3"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab4"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

I realize that tabs 3 and 4 are empty but even tab 2 still appears blank when I click it, only tab 1 shows the correct LinearLayout.

Answer (score 0):

In short, your `LinearLayout`s for tab1, tab2, and tab3 are children of the tab1 `LinearLayout`. **Your tabs should all be siblings of each other**.

Here are some other items that might help in your layout as well:

1. I'm not really sure why the `LinearLayout` with `android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"` exists, so I'd remove it;
2. You don't need to use `android:layout_alignParentLeft` or `android:layout_alignParentTop` in your `TabHost` because it is already matching the parent's width and height, so I'd remove those attributes;
3. You're using `android:layout_width="fill_parent"` on an `ImageView`. Instead, you should use `match_parent` because `fill_parent` is deprecated. See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html#attr_android:layout_height which says this about `fill_parent`:

> The view should be as big as its parent (minus padding). This constant is deprecated starting from API Level 8 and is replaced by match_parent.